# best way to emulate a python ie compatible browser

Tags: python, internet-explorer, web-scraping

What would be the best way to emulate a IE browser with python for scraping? I've found this script http://www.mayukhbose.com/python/IEC/index.php and was wondering if there was anything more updated out there! (that's able to fill forms)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrape, you can use a scraper module like `mechanize` http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: I've used mechanize before and it's excellent, but I need to run an IE window (changing the agent won't work) as the website only works with IE.

Comment: @Cat why does the website work only with IE?  does it use .NET?  Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Python Mechanize does exactly that:

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

It acts as a browser (i.e. you can go foward and backward, search and fill out a form on a retrieved page, post etc.)

Comment: Need to write me a screen scraper that will post to SO quicker!

Comment: I've used mechanize before and it's excellent, but I need to run an IE window (changing the agent won't work) as the website only works with IE.